# PyPy issue with shared libraries libffi.so.5

Tags: pypy

I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox. I've been trying to get pypy to work and it's so frustrating. I downloaded the binary and when I try to run it I get this error

`kimberly@kimberly-VirtualBox:~/Documents/pypy-2.2.1-linux$ ./bin/pypy

./bin/pypy: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I already addressed a previous error with libssl.so.0.9.8 and installed that and got that error to go away but now there's this one. I've been trying to get pypy to work for days so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You'll have more luck using our PPA, unfortunately binary compatibility on Linux, is at best, a mess, we've already got compiled PyPys available for Ubuntu 12.04; you can install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pypy pypy
```

Comment: @alex-gaynor, would this be possible in Debian as well?